# Specific type of continuity of an operator

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $T:X\to X^*$ where $X$ is some Banach space.

Under what condition can we guarantee that $T$ satisfies the following:

$$\langle x_n,Ty_n\rangle\to \langle x,Ty\rangle$$

whenever $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ and $y_n$ converges weakly to $y$?

Are there any known result what properties of $X$ are required such that this holds for the normalized duality map $J$ of $X$?

Comment: The usual duality $J$ is a map $X\to X^{**}$, so it wouldn't fit your question.